Shrinkwrap Object render Black in Cycles
I used Shrinkwrap modifier on a sphere to project it on a plane in shading tab even when using Cycles everything look clean and works, but if i try to render the shrinkwrapped sphere appears as black.
Already tried recalculating normals.image 1: shadingtab
image 2: rendered
file for downloading: file

Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See How to upload an image to a post? or GIF

Your sphere is smashed on itself because of the Shrinkwrap modifier, it makes the faces overlap which creates this black artefact called Z-Fighting. You need to use a circle for example, instead of a sphere.
